# Remove leading and trailing white space from dynamic JSON in angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs

I am facing issue while fetching JSON string dynamically using angularjs.

Here is one instance where I am facing this issue -

If a user enters any value on the UI in a **textarea** as follows:

```
<textarea type="text" class="form-control" ng-model = "inputAnswer" required="true" placeholder="Write Answer..." rows="1" style="resize:vertical"/>
```

and then I try to dispay it using the following code:

```
{{answer.postedAnswer}}
```

If the value of dynamically fetched string is as follows:

```
"123456789

abcdef"
```

I instead get the following value :

```
 "                                                      123456789

abcdef
                                                               "
```

I have tried using trim() method but it doesn't work for my case. There were some discussions on the JSON white space but nowhere I could see the issue that I am facing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post the actual code?

Comment: @PepeFloyd - I have added the code for clarification. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see to which JSON element you are referring to...but can you try this instead of self-closing element? 
    <textarea type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="inputAnswer" required="true" placeholder="Write Answer..." 
    rows="1" style="resize:vertical"></textarea>

Answer (score 0):

Here, to remove extra white spaces we can use combination of some Regular expressions.

Please see the example in the below link : 
[Removing Extra White spaces](http://kshitijshah9.blogspot.in/2016/04/sfdc-removing-extra-white-spaces-in-apex.html)

So we can use the above logic and store the modified value in Input field.